# Broadcasting events between unrelated components in Angular

Tags: angular

In Angular, is there a way to broadcast an event inside a component and then listen for the event in an unrelated component, i.e they do not share a parent and they do not have a parent/child relationship? I'm looking for a solution that does not use services.

I want to broadcast an event in component A. Then in component B or any other component that is interested, I want to listen for the event and take action when the event occurs. I want to be able to do this without needing a service to share the data.

I looked at the documentation and it seems the only way to share data between unrelated components is using a service. However, this leads to tightly coupled code.

Comment: Use services and observables to create an event bus. If service has `provideIn: 'root'` - they are shared among all the components. If you need to loose coupling - define interface and use injection tokens

Comment: A service with subscriptions and observables is perfect for your szenario.

Comment: A service in Angular is a special thing! It was exactely build for such szenarios! If you don't wanna use a service in Angular, you shouldn't use Angular at all. You are limiting yourself! HostListener will listen to events like mousedown, or keyboard events.

Comment: I agree an [Angular service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) is the correct and idiomatic way to pass data across a web app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this without using a service, but I think its the type of service that matters in this case. That means you can create a generic event service that emits and listens to messages. And then use this in both of the components. This allows them to communicate without needing knowledge of what the other one is.  Since it's so generic any component would be able to take advantage. The following code hopefully illustrates the point.

**EventService**

```
export class EventService {
  private events = new Subject<Message>();

  constructor() {}

  emitEvent(event: Event) {
    this.events.next(event);
  }

  on<Message>(type: string): any {
    return this.events.asObservable().pipe(
      filter(event => event.type === type),
      map(event => event));
  }
}
```

**Component A** - Emit the event

```
constructor(eventService: EventService) {}

doSomething(): void {
   eventService.emitEvent({data: [1, 2, 3], type: 'do-something''});
}
```

**Component B** - Listen for the event

```
constructor(eventService: EventService) {}

listenForSomething(): void {
   eventService.on('do-something').subscribe(event => {
      if (event.data) {
         // do something with event
      }
   }
}
```